# How to use sections/headings in a scrlttr2 letter?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, sections-paragraphs, scrlttr2

I use `scrlttr2` as a letter template? (Together with `mailmerge` in case that is relevant.)

How can I use sections or headings inside of a long letter to structure it?
Of course, I don't want to make use of a deeply-nested structure as in a scientific document, but just small headlines. They may not be a lot larger than the usual text and may just be bold. That is enough.

[I've found this German website](https://www.texwelt.de/fragen/9563/wie-verwende-ich-kapitel-oder-abschnitte-im-scrlttr2-brief), but it only eplains how/that you can use sections *outside* of the letter. But I want them to be part of the letter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Switch to one of the KOMA-Script classes `scrartcl`, `scrreprt` or `scrbook` and load package `scrletter`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Foo}
\opening{Hello,}
\blindtext
\blinddocument
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `scrartcl` and package `scrletter` you can also use `\minisec`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Foo}
\opening{Hello,}
\blindtext
\minisec{mini heading}
\blindtext
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was in the impression `scrletter` was outdated or so? Also where do I place the options for `scrlttr2` then?

Comment: @rugk to the contrary: `scrletter` is a rather new addition to the KOMA-Script family: “The `scrletter` package has supplemented KOMA-Script since Version 3.15. It also provides all the letter-based functionality of `scrlttr2` to the other classes.” (KOMA-Script manual “scrguien”, v3.28, p. 152)

Comment: Well okay, now the only problem is that the solution for another question @esdd has suggested does not work anymore now: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/578136/98645

Comment: KOMA-Script options can be placed as global options while loading the class, eg. `fontsize`, `paper` etc. Options regarding the letter can be placed as global or package options, eg. `firsthead`, `foldmarks` etc. You can also use `\KOMAoption` or `\KOMAoptions`. But note that Letter Option files (`lco` files) can only be loaded using `\LoadLetterOption` or `\LoadLetterOptions`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found an easy workaround by not using the LaTeX commands for headings, but just doing the styling manually.

Simply making it bold looks already very good for most letters.

Likely not the best, but works.

```latex
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Jerry Garcia\\710 Ashbury St\\San Francisco\\CA 94117}
\opening{Dear Friend,}

\lipsum[10]

\textbf{Case} \vspace{-10pt}

\lipsum

\textbf{Reasoning} \vspace{-10pt}

\lipsum
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image: preview of code]

Answer (score 1):

I did something really simple, just define in your preamble your own section command:

```latex
\newcommand{\section}[1]{%
    \textbf{#1}\\[2ex]
}
```