# What is the difference between scrletter and scrlttr2?

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2, scrartcl, scrletter

I'm asking about `scrletter` vs `scrlttr2` , because [it has been suggested for me](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578066/98645).

I know there is the huge doc about `scrguien`, but I do not have time to read that and want a quick summary of the main points.

See also: [How to convert a scrlttr2 letter to scrletter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/578133/98645). I've split the questions, because although they are related, they are different questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some differences between the usage of class `scrlttr2` or the combination of eg `scrartcl` with the **package** `scrletter`¹.

- With `scrlttr2` Letter Class Option files (`lco` files) can be loaded as class options or by one of the macros `\LoadLetterClassOption` or `\LoadLetterClassOptions`. With package `scrletter` they must be loaded by `\LoadLetterClassOption` or `\LoadLetterClassOptions`.
- Package `scrletter` loads package `scrlayer-scrpage` and defines a new pair of page styles `letter` and `plain.letter`.
- Package `scrletter` defines `\letterpagemark` to provide the formatted page number for the letters.
- With `scrlttr2` font elements `title` and `subject` are aliases for `lettertitle` and `lettersubject`, respectively.
- `scrlttr2` uses `fontsize=12pt` by default. Package `scrletter` does not change the fontsize of the class. Note that the main KOMA-Script classes use `fontsize=11pt` by default.

---

¹There is also an undocumented wrapper-**class** `scrletter`. It loads class `scrartcl` with font size `12pt` and package `scrletter`.

Comment: Why is the `scrletter` class undocumented? Just wondering.

Comment: I am not sure, see https://komascript.de/release3.27 (German) .

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I read the sections that mention the `scrletter` class, but didn't understand what it meant. I got the impression that the use of `scrletter` class and related classes is discouraged, though.

Answer (score 4):

https://ctan.org/pkg/scrletter?lang=en

says

> Used in conjunction with one of the Koma-Script (scrartcl, scrreprt, scrbook) or standard classes (article, report, book), this package provides the features of the letter class scrlttr2.

`scrletter` is a *package*  used as `\usepackage{scrletter}` typically used to give a standard `article` class document some features of a KOMA lettter.

Conversely `scrlttr2` is a class, used as `\documentclass{scrlttr2}`

https://ctan.org/pkg/scrlttr2?lang=en

says

> The class was designed ‘from scratch’ as a replacement for the standard LaTeX letter class.