# How to convert a scrlttr2 letter to scrletter?

Tags: koma-script, conversion, scrlttr2, scrartcl, scrletter

I'm asking how to switch to `scrletter`, when you were using `scrlttr2` before, because [it has been suggested for me](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578066/98645). I'd like to use the document class `scrartcl`, in case that matters.

I know there is the huge doc about `scrguien`, but I do want a quick summary of how to switch it and the main pitfalls.

See also: [What is the difference between scrletter and scrlttr2?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/578133/98645). I've split the questions, because although they are related, they are different questions.

### Example

My question is mainly about some options `scrlttr2` had and `scrletter` does not have. So e.g.:

```latex
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt,
DIN5008A, % load up-to-date DIN if it exists (TODO: or DIN5008B???)
sender,
paper=a4,
version=last,
fontsize=11pt,
DIV=13,
backaddress=false,
firstfoot=true,
enlargefirstpage=true,
% fromalign=false,
version=last,
parskip=full,
BCOR=0mm]{scrlttr2}
```

When I just change it and take all options to `scrletter` many of them are not recognized…

Comment: some of those options are standard koma class options `parskip=full` for example so you would pass them to srartcl not to scletter, but always if you want help with an error, provide a complete small document that produces the error and state the exact error message from the log. . Don't expect people to guess what error you had,

Comment: Yeah, I rather though/wanted this to be a gereric question/answer, so people can find/use it when they have the general question of how to switch the styles, what problems they may face and need to overcome etc.

Comment: `sender` is an unknown option. Is it a `lco` file?

Comment: I don't think there is a general thing, the basic structure is the same you may have a few things different, but you presumably _want_ some things different as otherwise why do the (presumably rather rare) thing of changing a letter from a custom letter class to a standard document class plus an add-on package?

Comment: Yeah, as in my case (linked at the beginning) you may need to add a new feature (headings) that `scrlttr2` cannot provide. Also `scrletter` is more modern and flexible, so you may also switch to this as a maintainance task to ease future changes in the design etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With **package** `scrletter`¹ Letter Option files (`lco` files) can not be loaded as package or global options. You have to use `\LoadLetterOption` or `\LoadLetterOptions` for them:

```latex
\usepackage{scrletter}
\LoadLetterOption{DIN5008A}
```

or if `sender` is a `lco` file too:

```latex
\usepackage{scrletter}
\LoadLetterOptions{DIN5008A,sender}
```

The KOMA-Script options `fontsize=11pt,DIV=13,BCOR=0pt,version=last,parskip=full`² can be set as class options by `scrartcl` or by one of the macros `\KOMAoption` or `\KOMAoptions`.

The letter options `backaddress=full,firstfoot=true,enlargefirstpage=true` can be set as global options by the class or as package options by `scrletter`.

---

Additional remarks:

¹ There is also an undocumented wrapper-**class** `scrletter`. It loads class `scrartcl` with font size `12pt` and package `scrletter`. With this class `lco` files can not be loaded as class options. You have to use `\LoadLetterOption` or `\LoadLetterOptions`.

² Additional remark: `BCOR=0pt` and `version=last` are default for all KOMA-Script classes. `fontsize=11pt` is default with `scrartcl`, `scrreprt` and `scrbook`.

Answer (score 1):

If I take the example from the scrlttr2 documentation

```
\documentclass[version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
Joanna Public\\1 Hillside\\SAMPLESTEAD\\WX12 3YZ%
}
\opening{Dear Madam Chair,}
Zzzz zzz zzz.
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and just do the things you state in the question, change the class to `scrartcl` and add the `scrletter` package, then it works without error.

```
\documentclass[version=last]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
Joanna Public\\1 Hillside\\SAMPLESTEAD\\WX12 3YZ%
}
\opening{Dear Madam Chair,}
Zzzz zzz zzz.
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My question is mainly about some options `scrlttr2` had and `scrletter` does not have. I'm sorry, I'll add a example.